# Generate set of numbers with a given number of 1s, 2s, 3s, and zeroes

Tags: python

I am attempting to resolve these components by getting inputs into the proper places and lists into the proper places.

I have tried some code regarding lists but this has not amounted to the result I sought out. The below is what I believe to be the basic skeleton, but of course it needs more help as far as including sample1 and sample2. Unless of course the skeleton must be changed to include sample1 and sample2 lists.

```
population = []
for i in range(10):
    population.extend([i]*10)

import random
random.sample(population,20)
```

I need to create a list (name it list_all) of 100 numbers that includes ten ones, ten twos, ten threes, ..., and ten zeros. Order doesn't matter. Create two random samples of twenty numbers each, where you are sampling without replacement (i.e., if all of the ones end up in sample1, there should not be any ones in sample2; in other words, the union of sample1 and sample2 is list_all). Importantly, I realize this needs to shuffled/randomized sample which is what you see above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tomothy32, hopefully that will make it clearer what I am getting at.

Comment: How can "the sum of `sample1` and `sample2` [be] `list_all`" if `list_all` contains 100 numbers and `sample1` and `sample2` each have only 20 numbers? Do you mean that the sum of `sample1` and `sample2` is *contained in* `list_all`?

Comment: @JackDorsey Questions don't ever "close" here because they've been answered.  People are always free to submit additional answers unless the question is marked as a duplicate.  As the asker, you're able to select the answer that worked for you as a way of marking it resolved but other answers may continue to be submitted.

Comment: @JackDorsey, ...also, note that we *actively disallow* deletion of good content. This both ensures that questions and their answers contribute to our knowledgebase for use by others, and it discourages people from cheating on assignments by ensuring that records of the questions and answers remain public.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating a single list with all of the numbers you want in it and then using [numpy.random.permutation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) or [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) to randomize the order.  You can then take the first 20 elements as sample1 and the next 20 as sample2.

For example:

```
# create list
list_all = range(10)*10

# shuffle list
import numpy
new_list = numpy.random.permutation(list_all)
sample1 = new_list[0:20]
sample2 = new_list[20:40]
```

Comment: There's no need for `numpy`, `random.shuffle` does the job fine.

Comment: True.  @Tomothy32  Do you know if they use the same pseudo random number generator under the hood?  For this small list it shouldn't matter much but might be a consideration for some applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing what you need for the first task (creating list_all). I would first try list comprehensions. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Another simple way would be creating a list with the elements you want and multiplying by the numbers of times you want them to repeat - not beautiful but works for this simple cases (similar to arrays).
`list_all = list_one * n`